# GetRoles() to take value directly from database

Tags: symfony

I give each user a role directly in a table.

the problem is, it throws error "Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object" everytime I'm trying to login.

if i change GetRoles() to `return array('ROLE_USER');` its working normally. but i can't retrieve the value from my database.

this is my User entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="xxx\yyyBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @orm\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $roles;
```

and this for GetRoles() function

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *roles* property has string type (look at annotations). So you can't call its method *toArray* (what the error message says).
Just write your *getRoles* method like this:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return array($this->roles);
}
```